# Conditional expectation limit to $-\infty$

Tags: conditional-expectation, expected-value

In my lecture notes, I came across the following:

Let $E(Y|X=x) = \mu(x)$ be continuously differentiable. Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have $\mu(x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} \mu(t) + \int_{-\infty}^{x} \mu'(t) dt$.

Apparently the first term $\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} \mu(t) = 0$, why is this?

Comment: As well the variable of the limes and the integration variable is $t$, which can cause confusion, could change the variables accordingly?

Comment: Any other information?

Comment: No there was no other information which I though was strange. Are there any certain conditions which causes $\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} \mu(t) = 0$?

Comment: Of course the limit you suggest cannot be always true, for example if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $\mu(x)=E(Y)$ for every $x$. But indeed the identity you quote from your lecture notes holds by the FTC, since for every $t<x$, $$\mu(x)=\mu(t)+\int_t^x\mu'$$